# java.util.PropertyPermission file.encoding read for signed applet

Tags: java, javascript, ms-access, applet, signed-applet

i have an applet that is called by javascript from an html page. the applet enters the value from the page to an access database.
i have signed the applet but still "(java.util.PropertyPermission file.encoding read)" error is showing..

UPDATE: Ive read that when a signed applet is accessed from javascript, it behaves as an unsigned applet. How can we rectify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the calls which need more privileges in `AccessController.doPrivileged(...)`.

Of course, first check that they are legitimate, i.e. they can't do anything bad even if called from evil JavasSript code.